# Using NSUserName() on C

Tags: c, macos

I'm trying to read the username via `NSUserName()`. I tried the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main()
{
    NSString *userName = NSUserName();

    printf("username %ls\n", userName);

    return 0;
}
```

and compile it via:

`gcc -o username -framework Foundation username.c`

Several things:

1- `#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>` generates a LOT of errors.
2- how can I convert an `NSString` to `char*`

on `1` I am adding the -framework switch to GCC but I think the Foundation.h is not ready for C? And on `2` I tried setting `char *userName = NSUserName();` but that wasn't the way to do it.

Any ideas? The code has to be C, not objective-C (as the title states)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you'd want to do this. OS X has a way to get the same information from C, and that way is `getlogin()`.

Foundation is an Objective-C framework and NSString is an Objective-C class. Calling it without employing Objective-C is not a simple task. Essentially, you will need to link in Foundation, include objc/objc.h for `id`, prototype `NSUserName()` yourself, use the Objective-C runtime API to get the selector for `UTF8String`, use the Objective-C runtime API to send the message to the string and then print the result.

All this to avoid calling `getlogin()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure-C equivalent to `NSUserName()`:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

struct passwd *pwent = getpwuid(getuid());
printf("Username: %s\n", pwent->pw_name);
```

As a bonus, this will compile and work on all UNIX-based operating systems (e.g, Linux), not just Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

change the file extension of the file holding your code from `.c` to `.m` and I bet you will have a better compiling experience.

On my machine, when I drop your code into a file named "MrAleph.m", here is what I get:

```
[/tmp]:;gcc -o test -framework Foundation MrAleph.m
MrAleph.m: In function ‘main’:
MrAleph.m:8: warning: format ‘%ls’ expects type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct NSString *’
MrAleph.m:8: warning: format ‘%ls’ expects type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct NSString *’
```

And to fix those warnings, just change one line of code to:

```
printf("username %s\n", [userName UTF8String]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need it to be able to compile in C, not objective-c

Comment: Then you cannot use Foundation framework, which requires Objective C API's and Objective C objects.  Perhaps Core Foundation has the same kinds of API's you are looking to use?